# How to get a particular argument in printf format in bash?

Tags: bash, printf, parameter-passing

It's needed to build a string `foobar is not foo and not bar`.

I'm expecting similar code:

```
$ printf "%1%2 is not %1 and not %2" 'foo' 'bar'
```

So, how to pass a particular argument?

my env:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: `printf` accepts the same formatting string as the `printf` in C plus some other options useful for shell scripting. Some of the additional options are also shell-dependent. However, it seems that repeating an argument at multiple locations in the format string is not supported or portable. You should pass the repeated argument twice, once for each position.

Answer (score -5):

The syntax is the same as in C printf function.

```
$ printf '%1$s%2$s is not %1$s and not %2$s' 'foo' 'bar'
```

Actually if you just need to concatenate some strings you do not need `printf`. You can use named variables in strings:

```
a=foo
b=bar
echo "$a$b is not $a and not $b"
```

Comment: The `bash` built-in `printf` does not support `n$`.

Comment: A non-exhaustive survey: It works with `zsh`'s and `ksh`'s built-in `printf`, as well as the external BSD `printf`. It does not work in `bash`, POSIX `sh`, or the `printf` that is part of GNU `coreutils`.

Comment: @chepner Which version of `bash` do you use? My 4.3.46 does not even have `printf` builtin.

Comment: `bash` has had its own version of `printf` since 2.02.

Comment: If you are using the `bash` built-in, no. It *may* work if you use `/usr/bin/printf` (or wherever your external `printf` is installed), but that depends on which version you have.

Comment: @chepner, so, I have `printf` from `coreutils`, and it's still not working... Ok, thanks for clarification. So, you may post an answer. I assume that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ea7ababe, Thanks for the answer, I knew this format but I was hoping there is some another approach for `bash` because it doesn't work.

Comment: @Kirby, actually, if you just want to concatenate some strings you do not need `printf`. You can use named variables:

Comment: Yeah, sure, I know. :) I just need to paste the same string 5 times, another string 4 time, etc... Of course, some replacement functions can be used, but that's another story. :)